# JQuery how to get the complete GET action values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url `http://localhost/mysite/conts?values=test&value2=tes2`

when the page is load this will be the output.

`<p>The Get Value is "values=test&value2=tes2" </p>`

I want to put all the complete GET value in my hidden input. Is it possible?

Comment: What is your expected output? what you want?

Comment: I just want to get the GET value from the URL the `values=test&value2=tes2` to be display

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to pass a parameter from a URL to a hidden form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251393/using-javascript-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-url-to-a-hidden-form-field)

Comment: the url you provieded their is no file are you providing url just like that @gadss

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, your conts page would look like this:

```
<?php    
$values = $_GET["values"];
$value2 = $_GET["value2"];
?>

<p>The Get Value is "values=<?php echo $values; ?>&value2=<?php echo $value2; ?>" </p>
```

Given your url: `http://localhost/mysite/conts?values=test&value2=tes2`, your output would be:

```
<p>The Get Value is "values=test&value2=tes2" </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
var url = "http://localhost/mysite/conts?values=test&value2=tes2";
$("#url").val(url.split("?")[1]);
```

Check value in your hidden field it is set to `values=test&value2=tes2`.